# Please, help me identify japanese font

Tags: fonts

Can anyone help identify a jap font,pls...tia[image]

Comment: You should try using likefont.com - it can sometimes find CJK fonts automatically.

Comment: Thx, i did it already, but couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok,so i've found the font...it's https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/4821
the problem is that i can't purchase it:(

Comment: Glad to hear you found the fond. Sadly, we are not able to assist with things like purchases or translations. Please use an online translation service or contact the foundry directly.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/117266)